# Navegar scroll horizontal ao pressionar tab

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Estou utilizando o plugin [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/). Construí uma tabela onde as quatro primeiras colunas estão fixas e as outras (que serão geradas "dinamicamente") possuem `input` para digitação de quantidade.

A minha intenção é que quando o usuário pressionar `tab` para ir ao próximo input, o scroll horizontal acompanhe, atualmente (com exceção ao IE) o `input` ganha focus mas como o scroll não se movimenta, ele fica lá escondido no overflow.

Segue imagem de como está minha tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso proceder para que o efeito desejado funcione (principalmente) no Chrome ?

Minha estrutura HTML:

```
<div id="novoPedidoTabelaA_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline no-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="DTFC_ScrollWrapper" style="position: relative; clear: both; height: 182px;">
        <div class="DTFC_RightWrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
            <div class="DTFC_RightHeadWrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class="DTFC_RightHeadBlocker DTFC_Blocker" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="DTFC_RightBodyWrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;">
                <div class="DTFC_RightBodyLiner" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="DTFC_RightFootWrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class="DTFC_RightFootBlocker DTFC_Blocker" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dataTables_scroll">
            <div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px; width: 100%;">
                <div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 3316px; padding-right: 0px;">
                    <table style="min-height: 100px !important; margin-left: 0px; width: 3316px;" class="table table-striped table-bordered top dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row" style="height: 56px;">
                                <th style="width: 307px !important; min-width: 357px !important;" id="produtoAlterar" class="TesteTeste sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Produto</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">Embalagem</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 113px;">Solicitado (QTD)</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 102px;">Digitado (QTD)</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 06/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 07/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 07/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 08/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 08/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 09/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 09/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 10/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 10/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 11/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 11/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 12/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 12/2015</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 01/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 01/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 02/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 02/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 03/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 03/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 04/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 04/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 05/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 05/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">1a - 06/2016</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">2a - 06/2016</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
                <table id="novoPedidoTabelaA" style="min-height: 100px !important; width: 3315px;" class="table table-striped table-bordered top dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="novoPedidoTabelaA_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
                            <th style="width: 300px !important; min-width: 300px !important; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" id="produtoAlterar" class="TesteTeste sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Produto</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Embalagem</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 113px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Solicitado (QTD)</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 102px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Digitado (QTD)</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 06/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 07/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 07/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 08/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 08/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 09/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 09/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 10/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 10/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 11/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 11/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 12/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 12/2015</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 01/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 01/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 02/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 02/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 03/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 03/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 04/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 04/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 05/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 05/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">1a - 06/2016</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                                <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">2a - 06/2016</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody>




                        <tr class="ListaProdutos odd" data-identificador="198" data-solicitado="12" data-nome="2,4-D 806 12X1 L" style="cursor: pointer; height: 99px;" role="row">
                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <h5 class="ProdutoDescricao" data-produtodescid="198" style="min-width: 299px !important;">2,4-D 806 12X1 L (DQDA.806.003)</h5>
                            </td>
                            <td class="itemEnviado">12</td>
                            <td class="itemEnviado">12</td>
                            <td class="QTDDigitadoProduto itemEnviado" data-iditem="198">12</td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-6-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-7-15" data-valor="8,5" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-7-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-8-15" data-valor="8,5" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-8-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-9-15" data-valor="8,5" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-9-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-10-15" data-valor="8,5" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-10-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-11-15" data-valor="8,5" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-11-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-12-15" data-valor="8,5" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2015-12-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-1-15" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-1-28" data-embalagem="12" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-2-15" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-2-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-3-15" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-3-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-4-15" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-4-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-5-15" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-5-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-6-15" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                            <td class="itemEnviado">
                                <input class="data" style="height: 10px;" data-data="2016-6-28" data-embalagem="12" data-valor="8,5" data-itemid="198" data-pedido="6" data-produtoqtd="12" type="text"></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="DTFC_LeftWrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 640px; height: 1px;">
            <div class="DTFC_LeftHeadWrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;">
                <table style="min-height: 100px !important; margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered top dataTable no-footer DTFC_Cloned" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row" style="height: 56px;">
                            <th style="width: 300px !important; min-width: 300px !important;" id="produtoAlterar" class="TesteTeste sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Produto</th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">Embalagem</th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">Solicitado (QTD)</th>
                            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 91px;">Digitado (QTD)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 101px;">
                <div class="DTFC_LeftBodyLiner" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow-y: hidden; margin-top: -6px; width: 657px; height: 101px;">
                    <table style="min-height: 100px !important; width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="table table-striped table-bordered top dataTable no-footer DTFC_Cloned" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="novoPedidoTabelaA_info">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
                                <th style="width: 300px !important; min-width: 300px !important; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" id="produtoAlterar" class="TesteTeste sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"></th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"></th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 91px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>


                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="ListaProdutos odd" data-identificador="198" data-solicitado="12" data-nome="2,4-D 806 12X1 L" style="cursor: pointer; height: 99px;" role="row">
                                <td class="itemEnviado">
                                    <h5 class="ProdutoDescricao" data-produtodescid="198">2,4-D 806 12X1 L (DQDA.806.003)</h5>
                                </td>
                                <td class="itemEnviado">12</td>
                                <td class="itemEnviado">12</td>
                                <td class="QTDDigitadoProduto itemEnviado" data-iditem="198">12</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="DTFC_LeftFootWrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="dataTables_info" id="novoPedidoTabelaA_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Mostrando de 1 a 1 de 1 registros</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como você está fixando as colunas?

Comment: eu fiz um teste local e não consegui reproduzir o problema no Chrome, você pode criar um snippet ou fiddle?

Comment: Boa noite Rafael, o problema no Chrome ocorre em que resolução de janela? Será que existe a possibilidade de você ter misturado dois javascripts, poderia auxilar?

Comment: Zoom 100% em janela maximizada em resolução 1366 x 768. Acho pouco provavel.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No chrome o que ocorre é o seguinte, ele só da o scroll horizontal quando eu entro com algum valor no input. Por exemplo, estão visiveis os inputs de 1 a 5, quando dou tab pro 6 e digito algo, ele da scroll.. Assim por diante

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa a noite vou tentar corrigir isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Aparentemente, ele só navega por inputs sem valores. Se o input tiver valor, esse funciona na lógica que eu passei acima. Da para visualizar isso pelo seu JsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o scroll navega apenas em `input` sem valor, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
 $('input').focus(function () {
    var val = "";
    var attr = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
       val = $(this).attr("placeholder")
    } else {
       val = $(this).val();
    }
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).attr("placeholder", val);
 });

  $('.data').blur(function () {
        $('.data').each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).attr('placeholder');
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
                } else {
                    $(this).val(0);
                }
            } else {
                $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).val());
            }
        });
});
```

A lógica é até que simples. No `focus` atribuo um valor nulo para o `input` e armazeno o valor antigo em um `placeholder`.

No `blur` vejo se houve uma entrada de valor, caso sim, atribuo esse novo valor ao `placeholder`.

Assim o `input` estará vazio toda vez que pressionar `tab`

Além disso, utilizei uma das `function` que o Guilherme Nascimento passou. Apenas realizei uma pequena modificação.

```
$(function() {
    $("td:nth-child(5) input.data").focus(function() {
        $(".dataTables_scrollBody").animate({
              "scrollLeft": 0
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Aproveitei a resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento e fiz algumas modificações.

Usando jquery 1.11.1, funcionou no IE 9.

Exemplo abaixo funciona para qualquer tipo de largura da coluna e funciona no final do scroll:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var fields = $("input[type=text]", $('#my_table'));
   fields.focus(function() {
    var my_target = $(this);
    var dist = my_target.offset().left + $('#my_table').scrollLeft() - 10;
    $('#my_table').stop().animate(
     { 'scrollLeft' : dist },
     200,
     'swing'
    );
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="my_table" style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 50%;">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

A ideia é você colocar `id="my_table"` na `div` que contém a tabela com scroll. Nesta tabela você pode adicionar células/linhas/colunas dinamicamente a vontade. O código vai funcionar.

Comment: Atualizei com a minha estrutura HTML que é gerada por conta da fixação de coluna do DataTables. Nessa estrutura eu ainda tenho o mesmo erro

Comment: Tá um pouco difícil de entender o seu código, pois não sei como você formatou a tabela. Porém sugiro você fazer o seguinte: adicione à classe `dataTables_scroll` esse parâmetro: `overflow-x: scroll;`. Isso pode influenciar na classe `dataTables_scrollHead`, então certifique que esta tenha `overflow-x: hidden;`. Feito isso, na `div` que você colocou `dataTables_scroll`, adicione esse id: `id="my_table"`. Use então o código javascript da minha resposta.

Comment: A ideia é você colocar `id="my_table"` na `div` que contém a tabela com scroll. Nesta tabela você pode adicionar células/linhas/colunas dinamicamente a vontade. O código vai funcionar.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei ao qual versão do *Internet Explorer*, mas muitos problemas são causados devido ao [QuircksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), para ajudar a evitar problemas deste tipo recomendo que use está meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

No entanto o problema pode ser com a `datatables` como você citou, eu não tenho a estrutura HTML do seu código (os inputs e classes usadas neles, então vou postar um exemplo genérico e você pode adapta-lo).

Primeiro acho que ao invés de `overflow-x: hidden;` você deveria usar `overflow-y: hidden;`, pois você quer um scroll horizontal e não vertical, estou certo? (apesar que o script que postei irá funcionar em ambos casos).

> Como o problema só ocorre no InternetExplorer você pode usar `if ($.browser.msie) {` para evitar aplicar o efeito em outros navegadores.

```js
$(function() {
        var tabela = $("#Tabela");
        var fields = $("input[type=text]", tabela);

        fields.focus(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            var fieldX  = $this.offset().left;
            var tableX  = tabela.offset().left;
            var scrollX = tabela.scrollLeft();
            var tdWidth = Math.round($this.parent().width() / 2);

            setTimeout(function() {
                //Delay para previnir o scroll automatico do navegador atrapalhar o $.animate
                tabela.stop().animate({
                    "scrollLeft": fieldX - tableX + scrollX - tdWidth
                }, 200);
            }, 10);
        });
});
```

```css
#Tabela {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

<div id="Tabela">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Coluna 1</th>
                <th>Coluna 2</th>
                <th>Coluna 3</th>
                <th>Coluna 4</th>
                <th>Coluna 5</th>
                <th>Coluna 6</th>
                <th>Coluna 7</th>
                <th>Coluna 8</th>
                <th>Coluna 9</th>
                <th>Coluna 10</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

### Problema com a tabela customizada

O seu problema aqui não é com a tabela, o problema é que você criou duas, uma é exibida 50% e fica sobreposta, e a outra (aonde se encontram os inputs) ocupa "100%", mas fica por de baixo da primeira citada. Ou seja ela funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que alguns inputs sempre vão ficar abaixo da tabela sobreposta. Então o problema não é com a tabela, mas sim com uma coisa especifica que você criou. Seu código possui inúmeros estilos inline além de vários itens que parecem não ser necessários, mas irei tentar reaproveitar o código, veja se funciona.

O elemento que parece usar o scroll é o `dataTables_scrollBody` então o seletor deve ser algo como `.dataTables_scrollBody`. Como o primeiro TD a possuir input na sua tabela é o quinto, então terá que usar este seletor `td.itemEnviado:nth-child(5) input.data` (altere se adicionar mais TDs). O código js deve ficar assim, ele irá levar o scroll da tabela de volta a esquerda:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("td.itemEnviado:nth-child(5) input.data").focus(function() {
        $(".dataTables_scrollBody").scrollLeft(0);
    });
});
</script>
```

Se quiser usar um efeito animado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("td.itemEnviado:nth-child(5) input.data").focus(function() {
        $(".dataTables_scrollBody").animate({
              "scrollLeft": 0
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Exemplo no jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krph0dh0/embedded/

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72630/navegar-tab-input-com-valores