# Navegar tab input com valores

Tags: jquery, css

Primeiramente não é a mesma pergunta que [fiz anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69458/navegar-scroll-horizontal-ao-pressionar-tab), é uma pergunta complementar.

Tenho atualmente o seguinte modelo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krph0dh0/embedded/) que funciona regularmente, você vai pressionando `tab` e o `scroll` horizontal vai navegando, trazendo o `input` que recebeu `focus`.

Porém, isso não funciona se o `input` tiver valor. Caso você atribuir um valor para todos os `input´ e tentar usar o`tab`ele até da`focus`mas o`scroll` não trás o mesmo, ficando portando "escondido".

Como posso solucionar?

Comment: Vou tentar ver, eu arrumei o outro. Mas não tive tempo de testar todas possíveis falhas e até refiz ele. Vou postar no domingo que tenho mais tempo para auxiliar acaso ocorra problemas.

Comment: possível duplicada de [Navegar scroll horizontal ao pressionar tab](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69458/navegar-scroll-horizontal-ao-pressionar-tab) . Você poderia apenas mencionar isso na secção de comentários da resposta que lhe ajudou a solucionar o problema, que a resposta seria atualizada com esta opção, em vez de estar a arrastar a mesma pergunta para uma nova questão

Answer (score 2):

Como o scroll navega apenas em `input` sem valor, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
 $('input').focus(function () {
    var val = "";
    var attr = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
       val = $(this).attr("placeholder")
    } else {
       val = $(this).val();
    }
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).attr("placeholder", val);
 });

  $('.data').blur(function () {
        $('.data').each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).attr('placeholder');
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
                } else {
                    $(this).val(0);
                }
            } else {
                $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).val());
            }
        });
});
```

A lógica é até que simples. No `focus` atribuo um valor nulo para o `input` e armazeno o valor antigo em um `placeholder`.

No `blur` vejo se houve uma entrada de valor, caso sim, atribuo esse novo valor ao `placeholder`.

Assim o `input` estará vazio toda vez que pressionar `tab`